# C: adding new node to linked list with previously dynamically allocated data

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

Assume we have the function

```
char **get_contents();
```

that dynamically allocates some array of strings, fills it with data and returns a pointer to it.

We also have an implementation of a linked list with the field contents and the function

```
void new_node(char **contents){
    list new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    new_node->contents = contents;
    ...
}
```

The function `void clear_list()` exists and properly frees the list.

Is this a good practice to trust the implementation of a linked list to free the allocated memory passed to the node constructor?
It doesn't seem so to me, but I can't see other option to save the array contents in the list as copying it may be inefficient due to it's size (contents may contain long text read from a file). What is the right way to solve the problem?

Comment: What is your concern about relying on the linked-list functions to free the allocated memory?

Comment: This is really an opinions based question. There isn't an absolute answer. Freeing everything in `clear_list` is one valid (and arguably common) way to do it.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I would agree that `clear_list` should only free memory that the list functions had previously allocated, not memory that was allocated by the *caller* of these list functions, who may still have some use for those arrays.

Comment: I concern about it because it makes the contents-handling program dependent on the linked-list implementation which harms modularity in some degree. We create new node with dynamic memory assuming it will be freed by the other module of linked list.